# drupal add products with video fields

Tags: drupal

I'm having trouble inserting videos into Drupal Commerce Products using various methods. I'm trying with the migrate module as well as a web crawler.

In the content type, there is a field_video which is of type "Youtube video." I need multiple videos here.

I can create this functionality with the web GUI, if I click "add video" and enter a new URL. However, I would prefer not having to crawl the page a ton of times or doing some crazy migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience with those types of fields, I think you would benefit from creating multiple video fields with a limit of one rather than having one field with an unlimited amount of entries.  I know this may not be the "correct" way to do it, but for your scenario I think this is your best option.  By the way, set it to your maximum amount of fields that you would like to have.  This is especially helpful if you plan on cloning this content type, because you can leave those fields blank and they will not render.